# Javascript - from keyword "something" to google search query "something."

Tags: javascript

Can any one give some pointers how to complete this assignment?

Is this even possible to do? Or do i need api, can this be done easier by jquery or something/api?

"http://www.google.com/search?q=" I imagine this should be somewhere..

thanks for your help ..

So it will convert keyword suggestons from ubersuggest something like that to the output you can just click the google link query..

HTML:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="3000" name="strings" id="strings"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <input type="button" value="Generer" onclick="getLongs();" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="3000" id="long_strings"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
  function getLongs() {
    var source_code = strings.value;
    var lines = source_code.split("\n");
    var total_lines = lines.length;
    var longs = 0;
    var longtail;
    for (i = 0; i < total_lines; i++) { 
      var words = lines[i].split(" ");
      if(words.length > 2) {
        document.getElementById("long_strings").value = document.getElementById("long_strings").value + lines[i] + '\n';
        longs++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where does `strings.value` get defined?

Comment: Thank you. I just want to put a keyword in a textarea, "something" and then this becomes a google search "http://www.google.com/search?q=something". Then you can click it.

Comment: So i just want my keyword to create a output like this : http://www.google.com/search?q="output"

Comment: See my edited answer below - it addresses the links issue

Answer (score 0):

I revamped your whole `getLongs()` function (see comments for explanation):

```
function getLongs() {
    var source_code = document.getElementById('strings').value; //properly access the input in the text area
    var lines = source_code.split("\n");
    var total_lines = lines.length;
    var longs = 0;
    var longtail;
    for (i = 0; i < total_lines; i++) {
        var words = lines[i].split(" ");
        if (words.length > 2) {

            //creates an <a> node
            var node = document.createElement("A"); 
            //assigns your link to the 'href' attribute of the a node we created   
            //use 'join()' to concatenate the individual words with a '+' separator for the URL
            node.href = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + words.join('+'); 
            //create a text node with the text value 
            var textnode = document.createTextNode(lines[i]); 
            //append the text node into our a node
            node.appendChild(textnode); 
            //append the a node to the #long_strings text area
            document.getElementById("long_strings").appendChild(node); 

            //create an add a <br> node to add separation between links in #long_strings
            var htmlbreak = document.createElement("BR");
            document.getElementById("long_strings").appendChild(htmlbreak);

            longs++;
        }
    }
}
```

[updated JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xjj05dj3/1/)

Comment: thank you thank you. Does this code create an output for you?

Comment: It does for all inputs longer than 2 words on a line. i.e. "hello there jim" creates an output but "hello jim" does not create an output. This directly follows your original code. Is that not the expected behavior?